# Is SPICE's transient analysis erroneous for converging diodes with 0 current?

Tags: spice, kirchhoffs-laws

Let's say you have 4 voltage sources, set to V1, V2, V3, and V4 with respect to ground feeding the anodes of respective diodes D1, D2, D3 and D4. What is the voltage across each of the diodes?

Consider [this circuit intended for mutual exclusion for a resource](http://www.partsim.com/simulator/#15304).

[image]
￼

In this circuit, each voltage source is producing a sine wave of different frequency.  Its transient analysis looks like:

￼[image]

The dark blue line represents the voltage on the wire that connects all the diodes together (at their cathodes).  The other colors represent the voltages of the respective voltage sources -- hence the voltage on the input to the diode (its anode).  Therefore the voltage cross each of the diodes is the distance from the dark blue line to their respective colored lines.

The thing to notice is the darker blue line is always just below, or on top of, the highest voltage at any point in time.  That means at almost any given point in time there is only one "winning" diode -- a positive voltage across it.  If a positive voltage sensor is placed across each diode, and that sensor outputs a binary 1 or 0, declaring if its sensed voltage is positive, we have a way excluding all but one of a number of "supplicants" from access to a shared resource such as a bank of memory.

However, this circuit has 0 current flowing, so where do the charge carriers come from on the shared wire to generate a potential difference?

Comment: Diodes have some capacitance, even when reverse biased, so there isn't quite zero current flowing if the model is accurate enough.

Comment: To make such a simulation work properly you will need to add a resistor between the common-kathode connection and ground. Without that, the voltage will be determined by **leakage currents** which can give unexpected and unrealistic results. With that resistor in place, the voltage at the common-kathodes will be the highest voltage from any of the sources minus one diode forward voltage (~0.6 V).

Comment: ^^^  this.   SPICE thinks that node is floating.   A 10Meg resistor to ground should fix things.

Comment: Even as it stands, it is leakage current through the other 2 or 3 diodes that is pulling the output voltage down slightly.

Comment: Look up three-phase diode rectifiers, you'll see the exact same thing.

Comment: @DaveTweed are you saying that the simulation is (even remotely) accurate even without the 10M resistor recommended by Kyle B?

Comment: Yes. There's significant negative bias across those other diodes, so if the simulation is modeling them accurately, there's enough current to do the job.